# What is the React way to the 'Single Item'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Let's say we have a list of items that we are iterating through

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = require('./ListItem.jsx');

var itemsList = [...]

var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var listOfItem = itemsList.map(function(item) {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} text={item.text} />;
        });

        return (
            <ul>{listOfItems}</ul>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = List;
```

And then we have the single item:

```
var React = require('react');

var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                <a href={Open THIS Specific Item}>{this.props.text}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ListItem;
```

Let's pretend this single item is a link, that will take me to a detailed page of that specific item.

How would we do this?

Comment: Like React Router, single page application style? Or do you want to reload your app with new data?

Comment: @azium It would be interesting to explore each way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would look at the react-router docs. It's pretty straightforward and you'll only need one ReactDOM.render call, which is typical for React. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Comment: #azium Thanks, I will read it!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a link via props, just like your `item.text`

In your List class:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var listOfItem = itemsList.map(function(item) {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} text={item.text} url={item.url} />;
        });

        return (
            <ul>{listOfItems}</ul>
        );
    }
});
```

Then, in your ListItem class:

```
var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                <a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.text}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.